# c++ Public member variable is inaccessible

Tags: c++

There's an error message "member ... is inaccessible" in Visual Studio when I try to access the value of a member variable.
But, the member variable is declared public.  It's a derived class, but it's not a member variable of the base class.
From the compiler, there's an error message "cannot access protected member".
The lines that cause the error:

```
    CKaltestDlg dlg;
        fprintf(debugout, "Reminders get input focus %s \n", dlg.m_ReminderInputFocus ? "true" : "false");
```

The header file.  The member variable in question is near the end, under a public: heading.

```
// KaltestDlg.h : header file
//


#pragma once

// CKaltestDlg dialog
class CKaltestDlg : public CDialogEx
{
// Construction
public:
    CKaltestDlg(CWnd* pParent = nullptr);   // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_KALTEST_DIALOG };
#endif

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


// Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
public:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedRemindersinputfocus();
    CButton m_EnableDisableInputFocus;
    BOOL m_ReminderInputFocus;
    CButton m_EnableDisableRemindersOntop;
    BOOL m_RemindersOnTop;
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedRemindersalwaysontop();
    CButton m_EnableDisableFlash;
    BOOL m_FlashTaskbarButton;
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedReminderflash();
};
```

Comment: Unsure but perhaps that DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP() macro messes up what is public and what is protected ... add public: after it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation of the `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc?view=msvc-160#declare_message_map) macro

> Note
>
> If you declare any member after `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP`, you must specify a new access type (`public`, `private`, or `protected`) for them.

So the macro expansion may result in the visibility being changed. Either move the macro to the end of the class or add `public:` right after it. I'd recommend leaving a comment about this in your code to remind you of this fact if you modify the class in the future.